# QPainter::begin crashes the program in debug mode

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, qt5, qpainter

**1. Problem description**

Calling [QPainter::begin](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#begin) works fine when the program is run normally, but causes it to crash when executed in *Debug* mode. Any ideas what is the reason for that?

---

**2. Environment**

- Windows 7 Pro 64 bit
- Qt 5.9.2
- MSVC 2017
- Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\cdb.exe

---

**3. Example code**

*MainWindow.h*

```
#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
};
```

*MainWindow.cpp*

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "Painter.h"
#include <QLabel>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto *label = new QLabel(this);

    label->setPixmap(Painter().paint());

    setCentralWidget(label);
}
```

*Painter.h*

```
#include <QObject>

class Painter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Painter(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QPixmap paint();
};
```

*Painter.cpp*

```
#include "Painter.h"
#include <QPainter>

Painter::Painter(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

QPixmap Painter::paint()
{
    QPainter painter;
    QPixmap pixmap(16, 16);

    pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);

    painter.begin(&pixmap); // <-- program crashes here on Debug

    return pixmap;
}
```

---

**4. Debugger's output**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the QPainter variable in your paint function not need to be initialised in some way?

Comment: @bennji_of_the_overflow how, for example?

Comment: I've tried it in Linux with Qt 5.9.2 and it works fine, maybe it's a bug that only happens in windows, I recommend you report it.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I suspect the debugger causes the issue, because otherwise it is working without any problem 100% of the time. In fact, ever since I've upgraded Qt to version 5.9.1 and 5.9.2 afterwards, I am experiencing problems with debugging. At some point not only the application, but also Qt Creator crashes while debugging. Though I don't know if I could reproduce that exact one with a minimal and verifiable example. Anyway, I would like to investigate further before reporting it to Qt. Today I will do the same exercise under Win 10 and see what happens. I will share the results, of course.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I confirm the issue on Windows 10. I guess I have enough evidance now to report it.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-64581

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reposting from bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-64581

If you begin painting by QPainter::begin() you would expect to have passed QPaintDevice and QPaintEngine is alive before painting is finished.
You should not destroy QPaintEngine while painting is active (end() is not called).
In the example QPixmap is destroyed before QPainter has finished painting.
Needs to call end() before or make sure that the pixmap is alive.